# Best practice for converting an object to string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've seen a number of ways of converting an `Object` to a `String` in .NET, typically for displaying the object's value to the user when the object type is not known.

These include:

```
Dim x as Object = 3
Dim y as Object = Nothing
Dim z as Object = DBNull.Value
Dim l_displayString As String

l_displayString = "" & x & "" & y & "" & z
l_displayString = If(x, "").ToString() & If(y, "").ToString() & If(z, "").ToString()
l_displayString = Convert.ToString(x) & Convert.ToString(y) & Convert.ToString(z)
```

Is there a method which is recommended by Microsoft, or do these all compile down to the same byte code?

EDIT:

Let me expand the question a little to include:

What are the differences between these methods? I can't see what's going on under the hood, so it'd be nice to know if there is any performance benefit of one over the others. In some cases, these calls may be made several thousand times (such as reading from a large table) and shaving off a couple seconds can make a big UX impact.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The  `Convert.ToString(x)` works gracefully even if x is null. In general, when dealing with stuff coming from database, I think Convert is the best approach. Another suggestion, when working with float/decimal numbers, keep an eye to the CultureInfo, ie don't trust the . as decimal sign, if you want to assume that use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Do you know if this is Microsoft's recommended standard? Any idea what, if any, overhead is introduced versus the other two methods? I'm not much of a CLR ninja, so I can't really compare them at the byte code level.

Comment: I think that in term of performance things does not sensibly change, is better to be safer.

Comment: Thanks - this was the most helpful answer. I added an answer with my test results and it basically confirmed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

They do different things.  They compile to different MSIL code, but in most cases they will probably have the same result.

`ToString` is a method defined by `Object`, which is the inherent base type for all objects.  By default it returns the object's type name, but it can (and often is) overridden by each type so that it returns a more meaningful string.  For instance, in your example, `x` is an `Int32` object, and `Int32` overrides `ToString` so it returns `"3"` instead of the default "System.Int32".

I'm not positive, but I suspect when you do the concatenation `"" & x`, it is casting `x` to a `String`, in which case it is a shortcut to typing `"" & CType(x, String)` or `"" & CStr(x)`.  Each type can overload the casting operator, so it assumes that the type (in this case `Int32`) has overloaded the operator and can therefore be cast to a string.  Indeed it has and can.

`Convert.ToString` does different things depending on which overload you call.  If you pass it an `Int32`, it just calls the object's `ToString()` method.  However, if you pass it an `Object`, for instance, it first checks to see if the object implements `IConvertible` or `IFormattable`.  If it does, it uses one of those, otherwise it uses the `ToString` method.  So, it tries, depending on the type of object you send it, to determine what it thinks it the most likely best way to get that type to a string.

As far as what is the preferred method, I would say `x.ToString()` is what you want to use most all of the time, unless you have some other concern (which all depends on what you are doing with the object).

Comment: I have discovered that CStr(DBNull.Value) will cause an InvalidCastException, but "" & DBNull.Value will not. So I do not think that it is casting the object to type string. But, "" & Nothing also works, so I do not think it is necessarily calling ToString().

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the enhanced capabilities of Convert.ToString - didn't realize it did all of that. The added reflection slows the function down a bit compared to calling ToString(), but the difference (see my answer below) is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to test the performance of each method using a collection of 1,000,000 objects. The objects were one of: an integer, a class, Nothing or DBNull.Value. The same collection was used for each test, and I tested each method 50 times.

`"" & x`
This actually doesn't work for all objects. It works for DBNull.Value and Nothing, but trying to use this method with just any ol' object will cause an InvalidCastException. Interestingly, CStr(DBNull.Value) throws an InvalidCastException, so I'm not sure why it works.

Results with custom object: **N/A**
Results w/o custom object: avg **126.7 ms**, median **126 ms**

`If(x, "").ToString()`
Results with custom object: avg **140.46 ms**, median **138 ms**
Results w/o custom object: avg **69.32 ms**, median **69 ms**

`Convert.ToString()`
Results with custom object: avg **171.54 ms**, median **171 ms**
Results w/o custom object: avg **112.14 ms**, median **112 ms**

So it would seem that `If(x, "").ToString()` is a bit faster for a very large set of records, but that would need to be balanced with `Convert.ToString()`'s more powerful conversion options. Thanks for the answers.

Here's the code I used for testing:

```
Option Strict Off

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim l_objectArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(Function(x) GetObject(x)).ToArray()

        Dim l_stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
        Dim l_testResults As New List(Of Long)
        Dim l_testIterations As Integer = 50
        Dim l_displayValue As String

        Do

            ' --------------------

            'Console.WriteLine()
            'Console.WriteLine("Conversion using string concatenation")
            'l_testResults.Clear()

            'For iteration = 0 To l_testIterations - 1
            '    l_stopWatch.Start()
            '    For Each o In l_objectArray
            '        l_displayValue = "" & o
            '    Next
            '    l_stopWatch.Stop()
            '    l_testResults.Add(l_stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
            '    l_stopWatch.Reset()
            'Next

            'Console.WriteLine()
            'Console.WriteLine("Average: " & l_testResults.Average())
            'Console.WriteLine("Median: " & GetMedian(l_testResults.ToArray()))

            ' --------------------

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Conversion using Object.ToString()")
            l_testResults.Clear()

            For iteration = 0 To l_testIterations - 1
                l_stopWatch.Start()
                For Each o In l_objectArray
                    l_displayValue = If(o, "").ToString()
                Next
                l_stopWatch.Stop()
                l_testResults.Add(l_stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                l_stopWatch.Reset()
            Next

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Average: " & l_testResults.Average())
            Console.WriteLine("Median: " & GetMedian(l_testResults.ToArray()))

            ' --------------------

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Conversion using Convert.ToString(x)")
            l_testResults.Clear()

            For iteration = 0 To l_testIterations - 1
                l_stopWatch.Start()
                For Each o In l_objectArray
                    l_displayValue = Convert.ToString(o)
                Next
                l_stopWatch.Stop()
                l_testResults.Add(l_stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                l_stopWatch.Reset()
            Next

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Average: " & l_testResults.Average())
            Console.WriteLine("Median: " & GetMedian(l_testResults.ToArray()))

            ' --------------------

            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.Write("Exit? (y/n): ")
            Dim l_key = Console.ReadKey(False)
            If l_key.Key = ConsoleKey.Y Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Loop

    End Sub

    Private Function GetMedian(ByVal values As Long()) As Long
        Array.Sort(values)
        If values.Length Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Return (values(values.Length / 2) + values(values.Length / 2 - 1)) / 2
        Else
            Return values(CInt(Math.Floor(values.Length / 2)))
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function GetObject(ByVal someNumber As Integer) As Object
        Select Case someNumber Mod 4
            Case 0
                Return someNumber
            Case 1
                Return New SomeClass(someNumber)
                'Return Nothing
            Case 2
                Return DBNull.Value
            Case Else
                Return Nothing
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Class SomeClass

        Private _seed As Integer

        Public Sub New(ByVal seed As Integer)
            _seed = seed
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return _seed.ToString()
        End Function

    End Class

End Module
```